# 2 SPDT relays as motor driver, flyback diodes

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors

I'm trying to use relay as high current motor driver. [image: 2 SPDT relay module] I'm not sure how to connect flyback diodes. This is my current sketch [image]I've read a lot of on DC motors, but I couldn't find anywhere a schematic for 2 SPDT relay motor driver with flyback diodes protection. Because of SPDT relays I can't short circuit the PSU (S1 + S2)

I'd be glad with any advice/guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration you have in your sketch looks like a good solution. Another approach is to use 2 zener diodes rated for just over V+, connect them in series in opposing directions, across the motor terminals.